# Функция не принимает 2 аргументов, как исправить?

Tags: c++, функции, исключения

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Iskluchitel
{
public:
    Iskluchitel(void)
    {
        cerr << "Работаю!" << endl;
    }
};

void Testirovschik(double n, double m, int nomer)
{
    if (nomer == 2)
    if (sqrt(m) - sqrt(n) / m)
        cout << "Параметр для z2 в порядке" << endl;
    else
        throw Iskluchitel();
    else
    if (((m - 1)*sqrt(m) - (n - m)*sqrt(n) > 0) && (sqrt(pow(m, 3)*n) + n*m + pow(m, 2) - m != 0))

        cout << "Параметр для z1 в порядке" << endl;
    else
        throw Iskluchitel();
}

void main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    double n2, m2;
    cout << "Введите x для z1: " << endl;
    cin >> n2;
    cout << "Введите x для z2: " << endl;
    cin >> m2;
    try
    {
        Testirovschik(n2, 1);
        Testirovschik(m2, 2);
    }
    catch (Iskluchitel)
    {
        cerr << "Программа устойчива" << endl;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

[image: Задание]

Comment: так у вас функция ожидает трех параметров

Comment: @Grundy Внезапно :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вам надо вместо

```
Testirovschik(n2, 1);
Testirovschik(m2, 2);
```

Написать

```
Testirovschik(n2, m2, 1);
Testirovschik(n2, m2, 2);
```

Это ответ на ваш вопрос. Но там много чего неверно, помимо этой мелочи.

Сначала проверяйте условия (с генерацией исключений, если надо), а уже потом делите. Типа

```
if (m == 0) throw...
z = ...
```

А иначе - ЧТО вы проверяете?
И еще - вы же сами выражения-то вычислите и выведите!

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо вам большое. Вот только не покидает ощущение, что я что-то напутал в условии. Так и есть?

Comment: @Роджер Так и есть. Вы же исключение генерируете не тогда, когда надо...

Comment: ох, теперь я окончательно запутался

Comment: Как намек для первой ситуации: if (m == 0) throw ...
z2 = (sqrt(m) - sqrt(n) )/ m;
cout << " z2 = " << z2 << endl;

Comment: Не получается...